# How do I make my discord.py bot count the amount of messages sent by a certain person?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord bot that is similar to mee6 in the sense that it counts the messages sent by a user in my Discord server at certain intervals. I have scoured the web and can't find what I'm looking for even though there are similar questions. For example, I was able to find some code that counts the number of messages sent in one specific channel. I was also able to find something that I am basically looking for, which is total messages sent in a guild, but it was written in Java. I hope this narrows my question, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to [produce a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code you have tried. What have you tried? What other pieces of code have you looked at? Include those facts in your question. Also visit [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the author and the message count in a `Dictionary` like this:

```py
messageCount = {}

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    author = str(ctx.author)
    if author in messageCount:
        messageCount[author] += 1
    else:
        messageCount[author] = 1
    
    await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

So, the dictionary would look something like this:

```py
messageCount = {
    'user#1532': 52,
    'user#0864': 742,
    'user#0067': 662,
    ...
}
```

---

**Note:** Once the bot goes offline, all the data will be erased, so i'll be a lot safer to store this data in an external file or a database. I'm hoping this answer will give you a gist on how to get started.

Comment: Perfect! I was entering in all the values one by one by hand based on mee6, but this makes it so much easier. It also answered another question I was about to search up. Thanks again!

Comment: @AdrianMaciuca no prob! Please mark this as the solution if it helped.

Comment: So when I tried implementing it, if there was no previous data for a user, it would not add them to the dictionary but would return no error. I then added myself manually with a value of 0, and it would not change. I think I'm missing something here, but can you help me again? Thanks again.

Comment: @AdrianMaciuca what exactly is happening? I tested my code before answering, it works correctly. You can try adding a `print(messageCount)` before `await client.process_commands(ctx)`. It'll show you what's in it.